# Resolving jquery script, onclick function in Opencart

Tags: toggle, opencart, multistore

I am using opencart multistore, with an addon domain.
And on my template there is a language.tpl where toggle between languages is being controlled. My visitors can switch between languages by a dropdown menu.
And this action is controlled by jquery onclick function.

My problem is, it switches languages within the same domain. For example:

Where product in "english" is urun in "turkish"
**(English)** example.com/product > **(Turkish)**example.com/urun

But i want this switch redirect to my addon domain. Such as
**(English)** example.com/product > (**Turkish**) example.com.**tr**/urun
by adding .tr to url.

Here is the script:

```
    <a onclick="$(this).closest('form').find('input[name=\'language_code\']').val('<?php echo $language['code']; ?>'); $(this).closest('form').submit();"><img width="16" height="11" src="<?php echo Journal2Utils::staticAsset('image/flags/' . $language['image']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /></a>
```

So is there a way so that i can add .tr to url.
I am open to other methods in doing this. Like php coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done this before. Before answer; please specify what version of OC you are using? Please also post the full code of the language link and the form?

Comment: It is better for you to answer and show full code and how you did it as it will save other people time and be used for future.

Comment: @Rüzgar So what is the solution? Post here your answer, please.